# What's an appropriate timeout for connections on mobiles devices?

Tags: java, android, http, timeout, connection

I was wondering if anybody knows, or has any information about, what could the best timeout for internet connections on mobile devices (particularly Android).

Since they have limited internet access with considerable lag, maybe it's interesting to set a smaller timeout (from default) since the device could be going though a network blackspot at that particular moment.

**UPDATE:**
This occurred to me, as I mention on the comments, since it can be rather annoying for the user to wait for a 30 second timeout and then have it fail in the end.

Comment: A smaller timeout? You mean a longer timeout? To me it doesn't make sense to say, the worse connection you have, the stricter I'll be with the timeouts.

Comment: Well so that the user is not left there hanging to wait if the connection responds. It's quite frustrating to see an app waiting for 30 seconds and then the connection fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Frankly I think you're asking a question with no real answer, or at least one where the answer is "it depends".

Here are a few things you might want to take into account though:

- Wherever possible, keep tasks using internet connections in the background. That way you can have a long timeout without keeping the user waiting. Hopefully this is stating the obvious!
- How badly do users want to get/send the data? The more important it is to them, the longer they'll be prepared to wait. So, a business app which is uploading business data could use much longer timeouts than a game which is just submitting high score.
- When using a mobile connection (ie. 2G/3G) there's a lower expectation of performance than when using wi-fi. You might want to take that into account.
- Being mobile, signal strength could be an issue. Again, it's something you might want to take into account.
- You could always let users set the length of timeouts themselves...

All that said, assuming you're blocking the user from doing anything else then I'd be looking at a timeout somewhere in the region of 10-20 secs. That number's more based on my experience as a user than as a developer though!

Comment: Thanks, great answer. The main issue is obviously with the fetch operations since the others can be batched easily and done in a service, but it's when you are searching or loading details that this can be problematic.

I think that the best solution may be to monitor the network signal and let the user that it may take longer than usual or fail. But then you need to add the permission for phone state so not the best for user trust :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing webpage then usually a 10-30 sec timeout is general practice and if you are accessing a json api than a smaller timeout example 5 sec or 10 sec is appropriate since size of data is usually pretty small in JSON response. A smaller timeout for JSON api allows users to wait less.

As you said it can be rather annoying for the user to wait for 30 second and then have it fail in the end. For mobile devices, the problem is there is no net access, so the sooner it fails is better and give an option of retrying for users.

What I'm doing in my app is monitor network state and set 10 sec timeout, if it still fails, users can do retries/refreshes to load data than wait for 30 sec and have it fail.

lastly as Baqueta explained well in above answer that how it all depends on situation.